# Dispatcher.forward and response.flush() in AJAX

Tags: ajax

I'm working on a Java EE based application and we are heavily using AJAX there.
In there we use two type of techniques to write ajax response.

1) Pass some data throgh ajax

```
res.setContentType("text/xml");
res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
PrintWriter writer = null;

writer = res.getWriter();
StringBuffer xmlDoc = new StringBuffer("<?xml version='1.0'?>");

xmlDoc.append("<selectChoice>");
xmlDoc.append("<selectElement>");

writer.print(xmlDoc.toString());
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

2)send complete jsp fragment via ajax

firstly ajax call servlet, 
then servlet set some variable sessions, 
and then forward into jsp page rendered the variable stored previously

```
RequestDispatcher disp = context.getRequestDispatcher(APP_pagePath + page);
disp.forward((HttpServletRequest)req, res);
```

in the first one as a standard practise we use flush() method. Then my question is how it is handling on second scenario (dispatcher.forward). In there we do not explicitly flush(). can you guys please explain the difference between these two and how the flushing handles in second scenario.